# Can't connect to my server Cisco EPC3925

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've set up my own gmod server(this is not a gaming question) and it was working great. Now I had some problems with my internet connection and my provider gave me a new modem so I got a new IP. I tried to start my server again but I couldn't connect to it. So I tried to look in my router and my port is still correctly forwarded to the ip of my computer. I tried to connect with the new IP and the port. So `IP:PORT` which normally worked. Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the make/model of your new modem and if you have a current static IP configured on your server. http://superuser.com/posts/727548/edit

Answer (score 0):

I think Matthew Williams has pretty much covered this.

Check your router cables are all correctly plugged in and arent dirty, reboot the router.

Check port forwarding.  If you are unsure on how to forward a port (or many), [This site](http://portforward.com/) is great for guides on all sorts of routers.

Also, make sure your server has a working internal IP and that you can connect to it successfully inside your network.

If your server has a static internal IP, cna you check that the IP, Subnet Mask, Default Gateway and DNS Servers it has are compatible with the settings on your new router (192.168.1.2 server can't talk to a 10.0.0.1 router!)

More info on your network setup may help us to diagnose further

Comment: For the vast majority of this we can assume it is correct (static IP and forwarding) since it has worked with his previous setup). The introduction of new equipment has changed something.

Comment: Could it not be that the introduction of a new router and not setting up forwarding again or new hardware on a different rancge could cause this problem?  Also, looking at your conversation below - it looks like thats EXACTLY what the problem is ;)

Comment: I highly doubt he has shifted his IP/subnet range etc. Unless his ISP screwed something up. Since it now appears to be a modem/router a port issue is now likely the issue.

Comment: Makes sense - although I'm sure we've both seen IP issues in this arena.  A new piece of hardware carries a new MAC, so a new external IP is very possible.  I don't know about his ISP, but Sky and Virgin in the UK both change their internal IP Schemes on a regular basis

Comment: His external IP will have changed along with a new MAC, but since he isn't binding the port to a MAC (instead using an IP) that won't be an issue. I have had a Virgin system in the UK for many years now and never had my internal schemes changed. This would totally screw up anyone with a custom internal network. Not sure why they would even want to do this.

Comment: They seem to do it from time to time (whenever they change the "superhub") - so the new hardware may well have come with a new IP Schema... was at least worth investigating and checking before spending hours investigating

Answer (score -1):

Starting with a simple one it could be a restart situation (from your wording I gather you have a separate router and modem, please clarify this):

1. Unplug your router and modem
2. Wait 30 seconds
3. Plug the modem back in and wait for internet light to stop flashing
4. Plug your router back in

See if this fixes it. You can test by pinging the internal IP of your server via cmd.exe.

*UPDATE*: So your issue is a new router on your system which requires a forwarding rule. So, assuming I have found the correct piece of equipment and you have a static IP configured on your server:

Log into your router via a web browser and default gateway > Applications and Gaming

Fill in the information to configure your port forwarding directly to your computer. Save the configuration and restart your router (switch off for 30 seconds). Ping your server IP to test it works.

At this point, unless you are using it for some other stuff you won't need your standalone router.

Comment: My old modem got replaced with a new one though I have no idea how to setup the forwarding rules. The router is still the same btw

Comment: The steps didn't work. When I check the ports if they are opened, it says the ports aren't opened.

Comment: Cisco EPC3925 I could use some help

Comment: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Cisco/EPC3925/defaultguide.htm

Comment: @Fazer87 Keeps saying invalid ip.

Comment: invalid IP when you try to connect to the router, or invalid IP when you try to save the configuration?  If its connecting to the router, use the IP of your computers default gateway.  If its saving the config, tell me what you are typing into each box and I'll try to help

Comment: @Fazer87 When saving the configuration. I use my Reserved IP Address which I typed into my router though which is 192.168.0.110

Comment: @Loko | Unless you need the separate router for something else remove it from your network. It will just get in the way now.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams I have to use my IPV4 Address right?

Comment: @Loko | Yes, that is the format of Cisco routers.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams Not working man it keeps saying invalid ip address

Comment: Lets continue this in chat | http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13527/discussion-between-loko-and-matthew-williams